# How to make xvnc not kill the session on exit

Tags: vnc

I'm implementing a remotedesktop access to a server thru xvnc/xinetd/gdm.

I'd like many users to connect to that server using vnc (thus providing the gdm login screen) and want that if the xvnc session is closed, it would 'xlock' the session so next time user connects it will resume his session.

Tried several parameter tweaks, but unfortunately each time the vnc viewer is closes, the X session is also destroyed.

Help/clues would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do it that way.  When the user disconnects, inetd kills the servers which were spawned for that connection.

Try using NX/FreeNX instead, it can do disconnect-session persistence. It can also allegedly connect users to an already running instance on the desktop, but I've never tried that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xvnc via xinetd, changing the xinetd "wait" parameter to "Yes", causes the GDM session to remain persistent between vnc sessions.  However, it does not auto-lock the GDM session.

here is the xinetd entry I use:

`service vnc1024

{

  disable = no

  socket_type = stream

  protocol = tcp

  wait = yes

  user = nobody

  server = /usr/bin/Xvnc4

  server_args = -inetd :1 -desktop lulu-loginvnc-1024 -query localhost -geometry
 1024x768  -once -depth 16 -fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc -SecurityTypes=none -Di
sconnectClients=0 -NeverShared

}`

make sure you add an entry in /etc/services as well:

```
# Local services
vnc1024  5920/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply,

I was already following the NX way ... Seems to do exactly what i want, oh by the way if you're interested, google just released a free version of freenx too called 'nextx'(http://code.google.com/p/neatx/) still in early stage but tested svn and works fine (until now).